# How do I get the relative path of a ASP.NET application from client side script?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, url

How do you get an ASP.NET application relative URL from JavaScript?

Comment: relative URL for what?  the current page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always generate a set of constants for paths that you will be using in a way which Javascript can see.  ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Paths = {};
    var Paths.Images = '<%= ...MapPath("~/images") %>';
    var Paths.Scripts = '<%= ...MapPath("~/scripts") %>';
</script>
```

Of course, you can adapt this to your app's needs.  For example, it might not be a bad idea to stick the initial declaration of Paths in a common js file, and have a method in your master page to add paths you will definitely need on each page.  Subpages can generate paths as needed, possibly from a helper method of some sort that generalizes the whole process.

edit: I've been thinking about this some more.  Here's a possible implementation, completely untested and probably not *exactly* right:

```
public static string RegisterPathsForJavascript(IDictionary<string,string> paths)
{
    var pathConstants = "";
    foreach(var path in paths)
    {
        pathConstants += string.Format("Paths.{0} = '{1}';\n",
            path.Key,
            Server.MapPath(path.Value));
    }
    return pathConstants;
}
```

and in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%= RegisterPathsForJavascript(new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "Images", "~/images" },
            { "Scripts", "~/scripts" }
        }) %>

    alert(Paths.Images);
</script>
```

Comment: I tested this solution in an ASP.Net webforms app. Besides the fact that the Server object will not be accessible in a static method, using Server.Path will send the physical paths in which your web application resides to the browser, e.g. "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite". I cannot imagine why you would want to do that. In any case, these do not include the 'ASP.NET application relative URL', as the poster requested. I'll post another solution.

Comment: Yup, you're right! Apparently I knew there was something wrong about it almost 4 years ago. :)

Answer (score 1):

Client-side code (JavaScript) has no concept of server-side component boundaries (like an asp.net app) so there's no nice and easy 'native' way for JavaScript to do that (that I know of).

The best (probably awful) method I've used to get around that is to have the asp.net app provide that info to the script when the page is served; there's a couple of options:

1. Include a hidden-field/TextBox/whatever and set the value of it to any server generated value you want; obviously JavaScript will be able to read the value easily enough.
2. Have asp.net/your app dynamically write/generate part of the JavaScript, when it does it writes the value as a variable where your other JavaScript can reference it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the application's relative URL, you can use

```
Request.ApplicationPath
```

which requires a request context.

To transform a complete path, use

```
System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(path)
```

which can be used without context.

If you are on an .aspx page, you can use the `ResolveUrl` method of the page.

For more information see [Different approaches for resolving URLs in ASP.NET](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.nl/2009/09/different-approaches-for-resolving-urls.html) as pointed to by @pranay-rana in [Getting full URL from URL with tilde(~) sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092523/getting-full-url-from-url-with-tilde-sign).