# Getting full URL from URL with tilde(~) sign

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get a typical asp.net url starting with the tilde sign ('~') to parse into a full exact url starting with "http:"

I have this string "~/PageB.aspx"

And i want to make it become "http://myServer.com/PageB.aspx"

I know there is several methods to parse urls and get different paths of server and application and such. I have tried several but not gotten the result i want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're in a page handler you could always use the `ResolveUrl` method to convert the relative path to a server specific path. But if you want the "http://www.yourserver.se" part aswell, you'll have to prepend the `Request.Url.Scheme` and `Request.Url.Authority` to it.

Answer (score 76):

Try out

```
System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("yourRelativePath");
```

There are various ways that are available in ASP.NET that we can use to resolve relative paths to a resource on the server-side and making it available on the client-side. I know of 4 ways -

```
 1) Request.ApplicationPath
 2) System.Web.VirtualPathUtility
 3) Page.ResolveUrl
 4) Page.ResolveClientUrl
```

Good article : [Different approaches for resolving URLs in ASP.NET](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/09/different-approaches-for-resolving-urls.html)

Comment: Note that the http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/09/different-approaches-for-resolving-urls.html article _claims_ "VirtualPathUtility will throw an error if there are Query String parameters in the URL", but I find that it _does_ work correctly even with a Query String.

Answer (score 10):

```
string.Format("http://{0}{1}", Request.Url.Host, Page.ResolveUrl(relativeUrl));
```

Comment: additional information: If you need port number, use it.

string.Format("http://{0}{1}", Request.Url.Authority, Page.ResolveUrl(relativeUrl))

Comment: This was useful, however, I used "Href()" in Razor instead of Page.ResolveUrl() because it throws a null reference exception.

Answer (score 5):

This method looks the nicest to me.  No string manipulation, it can tolerate both relative or absolute URLs as input, and it uses the exact same scheme, authority, port, and root path as whatever the current request is using:

```
private Uri GetAbsoluteUri(string redirectUrl)
{
    var redirectUri = new Uri(redirectUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    if (!redirectUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
    {
        redirectUri = new Uri(new Uri(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath), redirectUri);
    }

    return redirectUri;
}
```

Comment: If you mix the above information with this one, 'System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("yourRelativePath"); ' to resolve the '~/' path, then use this method on the string result of that. It works. (assuming not port information is needed) The combination of these worked for me.