# How do I create hyperlinks from resource files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have some text which is loaded from a resource file. Ordinarily, to get dynamic content I would use:

```
string.Format(GetLocalResourceObject("SomeText"), PhoneNumberAsString)
```

I want to do the same with a link, only the link needs to be application relative as I have URLs like `mysite.com/page.aspx` and `mysite.com/fr/page.aspx`.

I normally use an `<asp:HyperLink />` tag to create the links as I can then just put a squiggle at the start `NavigateUrl="~/page.aspx"`. However, I don't know of a way to get a dynamic HyperLink to appear as a string without adding it as a control to something.

Simply writing `ToString()` outputs `System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink.`.

How do I get a link out of a resource file and make it into a hyperlink using ASP.NET Webforms?

**UPDATE**

With some help from the answers I now have the following code on my page:

```
<p><%= string.Format(GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "MoreThan1000Users").ToString(), ResolveUrl("~/contact-us.aspx")) %></p>
```

and in my resource file I have:

```
If you would like more than 1000 users please <a href="{0}">call our sales team</a>.
```

Does this seem like good practice or is there another way to achieve what I'm doing? I don't know if I should be happy or not that there is HTML inside the resource file.

Comment: i truly dont understand your question

Comment: Are you asking how to replicate the ~ functionality? If so please read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092523/getting-full-url-from-url-with-tilde-sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't posted code, I'm guessing somewhere you have a HyperLink WebControl object that you're hitting ToString() on.  If that's the case, you can access the URL associated with it using its `myHyperLinkControl.NavigateUrl` property.

If you're storing the link in your resource with a squiggle/tilde (which is good) then you can replace the squiggle with your application location.  If you have a control/page, then you can easily call its ResolveURL method (which takes the tilde and automatically replaces it) There's some existing solutions if you don't have a control/page reference with your context, then there's some discussion to do that here: [ResolveUrl without an ASP.NET Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893380/resolveurl-without-an-asp-net-page)

Comment: You've definitely got me a solution, the issue now is I'm questioning my practices. Please see my update for my code. I suppose my issue is whether I should have the link HTML within the resource file.

Comment: Based on your edit, I'm not sure whether or not that should be a separate question.  Honestly, I haven't touched ASP.NET for a little while now so I'm not sure the best way to handle this, especially if your link is part of the text.  Perhaps you can have 3 separate resources (before-link-text, contact-us-link-URL, link-text) and you can put the link HTML in your markup.  You could have multiple references to the Contact-Us URL shared via the reference.  But maybe your best bet is to have that as a new question so more experienced people can find and answer it.

Comment: Ahh, I see you've edited quite a bit of the question.  Hopefully there's a good solid practice for this.  I know if I was making it, I'd probably straight up have separate controls handling the appearance/markup and leave resources for filling in the text content or shared URLs.

Comment: Haha I totally had that three resources thing you mentioned!! Then I decided it looked too messy so I ripped it out and stuck the HTML in the resource! But yes you're right it's more of a resources-best-practice question so I will ask a new question for my answer to that, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want:

```
Server.MapPath("~/page.aspx")
```

That will work inside your aspx and your code-behind.