# Accessing page in the root directory from page of another folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a folder in the root directory called ucontrol.This folder has a page header.ascx which has a link

```
<li><a href="/~/logout.aspx" class="nitem" ><i class=" glyphicon nitem " ></i>Logout</a></li>
```

This logout.aspx page is in the root directory.

How do i access logout page from this file in ucontrol folder.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
<li><a href="../logout.aspx" class="nitem" ><i class=" glyphicon nitem " ></i>Logout</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this like below

```
<li>
    <a href="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/logout.aspx") %>" class="nitem" >
        <i class=" glyphicon nitem " ></i>Logout
    </a>
</li>
```

This will fix your issue. For more information have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/9092554/1433093