# Displaying image in web application

Tags: c#, .net, image

i have problem with displaying image in my web app. It took photo from database, and should dispay in web app.

```
  protected void btnShowPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string adresURL = @"~/Content";
        string camPath = "";
        string[] tab = new string[10];

        CheckBox[] _boxes = new CheckBox[] { this.CheckBox1, this.CheckBox2, this.CheckBox3, this.CheckBox4, this.CheckBox5, this.CheckBox6, this.CheckBox7, this.CheckBox8 };
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image[] _images = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image[] { this.Image1, this.Image2, this.Image3, this.Image4, this.Image5, this.Image6, this.Image7, this.Image8 };
        Label[] _labels = new Label[] { this.lblCameraName1, this.lblCameraName2, this.lblCameraName3, this.lblCameraName4, this.lblCameraName5, this.lblCameraName6, this.lblCameraName7, this.lblCameraName8 };
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor[] _linkscontrol = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor[] { this.imagelink1, this.imagelink2, this.imagelink3, this.imagelink4, this.imagelink5, this.imagelink6, this.imagelink7, this.imagelink8 };

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            _images[i].Visible = false;
            _labels[i].Visible = false;
            _linkscontrol[i].HRef = "";
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            if (_boxes[i].Checked)
            {
                camPath = null;
                tab = null;

                camPath = this.GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;


                tab = camPath.Split(new string[] { "StoredPhotos" }, StringSplitOptions.None);


                //Virtual Path'a
                camPath = adresURL + tab[1].Replace(@"\", "/");

                _labels[i].Visible = true;
                _labels[i].Text = this.GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;

                _linkscontrol[i].HRef = camPath;

               _images[i].ImageUrl = camPath;
               _images[i].Visible = true;


            }
            else
            _images[i].Visible = false;

        }


    }
```

I have problem with my virtual path probably. CamPath(Virtual Path) becomes from : E:\Photo\StoredPhotos\20151010\000003819619_201512021335_1_C1, and finally looks: ~/20151010/000003819619_201512021335_1_C1

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser expect access to image via http protocol, if you want view the image you have 2 diffrerent way:

1. (simple) Create a virtual directory under iis that point to a phisical folder E:\Photo\StoredPhotos\ and called StoredPhotos, in _images[i].ImageUrl you may set the value /StoredPhotos/20151010/000003819619_201512021335_1_C1.jpg
2. (complex) Build a class that read the file on the disk and write it to the response (use IHttpHandler interface), add this handler to web.config and set _images[i].ImageUrl the value of 'NameOfHandler.aspx?20151010/000003819619_201512021335_1_C1

Answer (score 1):

This path means nothing to a web browser:

```
~/20151010/000003819619_201512021335_1_C1
```

It doesn't know what to do with that `~` directory.  That's a server-side concept, not a client-side concept.  So your server-side code needs to resolve that to an actual path.

It could be as simple as just explicitly starting from the root of the server:

```
string adresURL = @"/Content";
```

So the resulting URL would start with `/Content/.....` and the browser would check for the image in that path.

But if the application isn't (or might not be) the root of the server domain then you'd need to either manually account for that or use a server-side helper of some sort.  There are [a variety of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092523/getting-full-url-from-url-with-tilde-sign) to go about that, for example:

```
_images[i].ImageUrl = System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(camPath);
```

Comment: @"/Content" doesnt work.., ToAbsolute(camPath) - also. I will try different ways. TY.

Comment: @mistiq: You have to be more specific than "doesn't work".  What *does* it do and *exactly* how does it fail?

Comment: Ok. sorry. It means, that results are the same as previous, as you can see above.

Comment: @mistiq: All you're showing in the question is a picture of a broken image on a web page.  That doesn't provide any information aside from "it doesn't work".  What is the actual HTML element being generated?  What is the URL that the browser is looking for?  What is the server's response when that URL is requested?  Does that URL exist?  Is the file there?  You need to provide information for anybody to help you.

Comment: Yest, thats the element what my browser displays . And only this. Image.url: '/Content/201549/000003819546_201512021121_3_C3.jpg'. Yes, file exists., Url, also exists.

Comment: @mistiq: What happens when you try to navigate to that URL manually in your browser?

Comment: With this one: /Content/201549/000003819546_201512021121_3_C3.jpg? Google turn on.. Im new at .Not apps. Excuse my mistakes.

Comment: @mistiq: If your website is *forwarding that URL to Google* then that would explain why the image isn't showing...  Are you sure you navigated to *the entire URL*?  (Hint: URLs often begin with a server.)